# Sorting a hash map first according to value, then key secondarily

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I need to sort a hash map, first according to value then according to key.

```
TreeMap<String,Integer> dictionary = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
```

For example, the desired output is something like:

```
it - 2
of - 2
the - 2
times - 2
was - 2
best - 1
worst - 1
```

I tried tree map, but that only sorts it according to key.
So basically, I need to sort my first according to the Integer (Highest to Lowest) and then according to the String (First A then B till Z).
I searched online and saw that I'm gonna have to use comparator but I'm not sure how to make it work? 
Any guidance will be appreciated.

This is for a Java assignment.

Comment: You should probably identify the language with a tag (is it C++?).  You should also show your desired output — or is that what you've shown already?  Dickens didn't mention zebras as far as I can recall: ["It was the best of times, it was the worst of times…"](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/A_Tale_of_Two_Cities). ☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Map interface has no concept of "order", but you could sort the *entries*:

```
Map<String, Integer> map; // populated
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<> (map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
    public int compareTo(Map.Entry<String, Integer> a, Map.Entry<String, Integer> b) {
        return a.getValue().equals(b.getValue()) ? a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey()) : Integer.compareTo(b.getValue(), a.getValue());
    }
});
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : entries)
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
```

If java 8 is available, it becomes a lot neater:

```
Map<String, Integer> map; // populated
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted( (a, b) -> a.getValue().equals(b.getValue()) ? a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey()) : Integer.compareTo(b.getValue(), a.getValue()))
    .map(e -> entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If absolutely need a map, load them into a`LinkedHashMap`, which "preserves order" in that it iterates over its entries in the same order they were inserted.

Comment: @locha fixed comparison by reversing order (rather then `-diff`). Also, what's wrong with iterating entry set?

Comment: @Loc Ha How can I apply the above method to the linkedhashmap... I have the made the methods to add them to the linkedhashmap and they work.. I am just not able to make the above method apply to the linkedhashmap.

Comment: @bawa collect the results into a new LinkedHashMap

Comment: you appear to be missing a closing bracket in `new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>()`

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming this is something like Java).  Sorted maps only deal with keys, not values.  You probably want to just load the map content into a new TreeMap where each key is the original key and value combined somehow.  Or, you can load into an List and sort that, or use a Set.